# How to simplify ab + a'b'? Is there a gate for this?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I am simplifying the sum part of a full adder. The equation I get is:

$$x \cdot \overline y \cdot \overline {cin} + \overline x \cdot \overline y \cdot cin + x \cdot y \cdot cin + \overline x \cdot y \cdot \overline {cin}$$

How do I simplify this to get the two xor gates that make up the sum part of a full adder?

Comment: ab + a'b' = XNOR.

Comment: there are only a few basic rules in logic reduction. Do you know them?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Are you sure? http://www.bscshortnote.com/what-is-full-adder/ according to this is it correct. I just want to know, how to go from above to x xor y xor cin

Comment: @studious You've got your answer and it is easily verifiable. No need to ask people if they are sure.

Comment: i can't verify it that is why I asked this question

Comment: Can't you type XNOR in google and click on the first wikipedia link??

Comment: @studious now that you've added the bars over Cin, the equation you have for the sum is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use the various laws of Boolean algebra to go from the equation you have to a pair of XOR gates, it is not too tricky, you just have to spot similarities.

Lets look at your equation, what can we do?

$$x \cdot \overline y \cdot \overline c + \overline x \cdot \overline y \cdot c + x \cdot y \cdot c + \overline x \cdot y \cdot \overline c$$

1. Try taking out factors:

   Notice there are some \$c\$ terms in common:

   $$\begin{align}
     x \cdot \overline y \cdot \overline c + \overline x \cdot y \cdot \overline c &= (x \cdot \overline y + \overline x \cdot y) \cdot \overline c\\
     \overline x \cdot \overline y \cdot c + x \cdot y \cdot c &= (\overline x \cdot \overline y + x \cdot y) \cdot c\\
     \end{align}$$

   That would leave us with:

   $$(\overline x \cdot \overline y + x \cdot y) \cdot c + (x \cdot \overline y + \overline x \cdot y) \cdot \overline c$$
2. Using the standard table of Boolean algebra functions, we can easily spot the XNOR and XOR gates:

$$(\overline x \cdot \overline y + x \cdot y) \cdot c + (x \cdot \overline y + \overline x \cdot y) \cdot \overline c = \overline{(x \oplus y)}\cdot c + (x \oplus y)\cdot\overline c$$

3. Lets add a dummy variable to see things more clearly. Let \$d = (x \oplus y)\$. Then substitute it in to the above:

$$\overline{(x \oplus y)}\cdot c + (x \oplus y)\cdot\overline c = \overline d \cdot c + d \cdot \overline c$$

4. Spot the XOR gate there?

$$\overline d \cdot c + d \cdot \overline c = d \oplus c$$

5. Finally, lets plop back in \$d\$.

$$d \oplus c = (a \oplus b) \oplus c $$

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume (or else just put it squarely in front of you) that you know how to set up the logic using "*two xor gates*" to make a sum:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8xW6c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It doesn't matter how those three inputs are arranged, as they can be in any of the six possible permutations and it will still perform the same function.

You are trying to re-arrange a formula you have into one that provides you with the above arrangement (or one of the equivalent ones.) Why not start out writing down (which you didn't do) what the above pair of XOR gates looks like in a logic equation?

Well, all you need to know to do that is to remember (or construct by hand, if needed) the idea that \$A \oplus B=A\cdot\overline{B}+\overline{A}\cdot B\$. Now, just do the transformation:

$$\begin{align*}
SUM &= (A \oplus B) \oplus C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= \left(A\cdot\overline{B}+\overline{A}\cdot B\right) \oplus C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= \left(A\cdot\overline{B}+\overline{A}\cdot B\right) \cdot \overline{C_{in}} + \overline{\left(A\cdot\overline{B}+\overline{A}\cdot B\right)} \cdot C_{in} \\
 \\
 &=A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot \overline{C_{in}}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot \overline{C_{in}} + \left(\overline{A\cdot\overline{B}}\cdot\overline{\overline{A}\cdot B}\right) \cdot C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot \overline{C_{in}}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot \overline{C_{in}} + \left(\left(\overline{A}+B\right)\cdot\left(A+\overline{B}\right)\right) \cdot C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot \overline{C_{in}}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot \overline{C_{in}} + \left(\overline{A}\cdot A+ A\cdot B+\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}+\overline{B}\cdot B\right)\cdot C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot \overline{C_{in}}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot \overline{C_{in}} + \left(A\cdot B+\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\right)\cdot C_{in} \\
 \\
 &= A\cdot\overline{B}\cdot \overline{C_{in}}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot \overline{C_{in}} + A\cdot B\cdot C_{in}+\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\cdot C_{in}
\end{align*}$$

Can you see now how to get there?